Automatic login after Chrome update
I am using Chrome browser and Selenium Webdriver for the automation testing. Looks like after updating Chrome to v.126 or v.128 Chrome uses windows credentials to login to the app when I am running autotests.
Incognito mode successfully has fixed this issue, however some features are disabled in the incognito mode and I need default mode.
I set Internet Options -> Security Settings -> User Authentication -> Prompt for user name and password but it doesn't work.

by default Selenium will create a temporary profile to use... (which is essentially the same as Incognito mode)  Is this a negotiated domain login? Intranet?  Usually people want the opposite (no prompt).... but if you really want it, you might just explicitly add the intranet URL to the untrusted zone...  (internet settings at the OS level)  It sort of sounds like you are setting a profile when initializing the driver. (and this is not a domain level login)  Can you include your driver initialization code?
